# Singular Points of $\sin(x)y''+y=0$. Review my work

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to classify the singular points of the second order
$$\sin(x)y´´+y=0$$

Where, in its standar form:
$$y´´+\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}y=0$$

With

$$P(x)=0,  Q(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}$$

As far as I can tell, the singular points are
$$x_0=n\pi, \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

So, there are infinite singular points? Which all of them are **irregular** since there is at most 1 power of $(x-x_0)$ in $P(x)$ (there is non) and there is not a power of 2 in $Q(x)$.

I other words, both $(x-x_0) P(x)$ remains finite as $x\to n\pi$ but $(x-x_0)^2 Q(x)$ doesn´t.

$$\lim_{x\to n\pi}{(x-n\pi)P(x)}=\lim_{x\to n\pi}{0}=0$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to n\pi}{(x-n\pi)^2Q(x)}=\lim_{x\to n\pi}{(x-n\pi)^2\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}}$$

Does not exist.

Comment: The singular points are regular ones since the limit is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{x\to n\pi}{(x-n\pi)^2Q(x)}=\lim_{x\to n\pi}{(x-n\pi)^2\dfrac{1}{\sin(x)}}$$
Note that:
$$L=\lim_{z\to 0}{\dfrac{z^2}{\sin(z+n\pi)}}$$
And we also have:
$$\sin (z+n \pi)=(-1)^n\sin z$$
$$\lim_{z\to 0}{\dfrac{z}{\sin(z)}}=1$$
So that we have:
$$L=\lim_{z\to 0}{\dfrac{(-1)^nz^2}{\sin(z)}}=\lim_{z\to 0}{{(-1)^nz}} \dfrac z{\sin(z)}$$
Looks like the limit tends to zero as $z \to 0$

Answer (score 1):

$$\underset{z\to k \pi }{\text{lim}}\frac{z-k \pi }{\sin (z)}=\underset{z\to k \pi }{\text{lim}}\frac{1 }{\cos (z)}=(-1)^k$$
As the limit is nonzero for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $k\pi$ are simple  poles. Furthermore
$$\underset{z\to k \pi }{\text{lim}}\frac{(z-k \pi )^2}{\sin (z)}=0$$
thus $z=k\pi$ are  regular singular points.